# Particle Physics : Conservation laws

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws

As a whole, is conservation of a Lepton number valid, or is it basically the generalization of conservation of electron and muon numbers?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, conservation of lepton number is the *only* one of those that actually holds! Neutrino oscillations, which do occur in our universe, violate the conservation of electronic, muonic and tauonic lepton numbers separately. Therefore, only total lepton number is really conserved.

Comment: Even the overall conservation of lepton number fails if neutrinos are Majorana particles (a fact not yet known but beginning to look less likely). After all, the signature event for determining that is neutrinoless double beta decay.

Comment: Right, but that has not been detected yet, has it?